# How to convert from value with Any type to Real?

Tags: racket, typed-racket

I'm playing with Racket-Stamps, which is a mix of typed and regular Racket.

I'm writing a new feature and the code below attempts to call a function with a list of Reals, however because this list comes from untyped racket, it is actually a list of Any:

```
(define bounding (make-parameter '()))

;; snip

(when (not (empty? (bounding)))
  (let-values ([(x1 y1 x2 y2) (apply values (bounding))])
    (send pr set-bounding x1 y1 x2 y2)))
```

And in another file that calls the code above:

```
(bounding '(-20 -100 100 2))
```

Here's the error:

Type Checker: Bad arguments to function in `apply':
Domains: a b ... b
         #f *
Arguments: (Listof Any) *
 in: (apply values (bounding))

So how do I convert the `Listof Any` to a `Listof Real`?

Comment: I've discovered that I can make an empty list of Real with the `ann` function, so: `(define bounding (make-parameter (ann '() (Listof Real))))` -- however I still get the error about `apply`, maybe it's something to do with `make-parameter` and `values`?

Comment: `apply` isn't very smart for most cases in Typed Racket. Especially since you have an arbitrary-length list as input, and a fixed number of values (4 of them) expected as output.

Comment: Also, if you look at the type of `values`, it allows either zero things or one-or-more things, but not zero-or-more things. I would try to design this without using `(apply values ...)`.

Comment: If you use `(match-let ([(list x1 y1 x2 y2) (bounding)]) ...)` instead, does it work?

Comment: `match-let` works, many thanks Alex.

Comment: Do one of you want to write this up as an answer? If not I would be happy to.

Comment: Okay, I've written my answer. It actually ended up being something different, `let-values` with `apply values` is okay as long as it knows the list has exactly 4 numbers in it.

Comment: @EricClack I don't think `match-let` is needed. You can do it with `let-values` if `bounding` has the right type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `apply` function here is given an arbitrary-length list as input, but the context expects exactly 4 values. If the list had any length other than 4, it would fail.

It seems like you meant for `bounding` to contain either the empty list or a list of *exactly 4* real numbers.

```
(: bounding : (Parameterof (U Null (List Real Real Real Real))))
(define bounding (make-parameter '()))
```

Then every time your program tests whether the contents of `(bounding)` are empty and then relies on it being a list of 4 numbers, you need to put the value in a local variable first, so that Typed Racket sees the connection between the `(not (empty? ...))` test and the use below it.

In other words, transform the pattern

```
(if (not (empty? (bounding)))
    (.... (bounding) ....)
    ....)
```

Into

```
(let ([bounding-v (bounding)])
  (if (not (empty? bounding-v))
      (.... bounding-v ....)
      ....))
```

In your example, that transformation gives:

```
(: bounding : (Parameterof (U Null (List Real Real Real Real))))
(define bounding (make-parameter '()))

....

(let ([bounding-v (bounding)])
   (when (not (empty? bounding-v))
     (let-values ([(x1 y1 x2 y2) (apply values bounding-v)])
       (send pr set-bounding x1 y1 x2 y2))))
```